# how to enable minor tick for all the plots (matplotlibrc)

Tags: matplotlib

In matplotlib I can enable the minor ticks with

```
ax.minorticks_on()
```

is there a way to set it by default for all the plots? In `matplotlibrc` I don't see any option about this.

Comment: I guess they are still working on it!! [Look at this page](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3024)